# Different strokes in SVG-subpaths

Tags: svg, raphael

Is it possible to draw different strokes (I want different line widths) in a subpath of SVG?

I know this can be accomplished using different paths, but it is not possible to use use line-joins on different paths. I want to use a line-join round with different line width.

If it is not possible, what is the best techique to draw two connected lines with different strokes (in the picture below the lines are not connected)?
[image]

Comment: I'm considering an option to draw each line as a rectangle or separate paths with custom shaped end-points, connecting them using translate instead.

Comment: So very late, but just in case it might be useful to you or other people… You can most likely achieve the desired result with end-caps. For example, you may use stroke-linecap: square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path element only has one stroke-width property, so it's not possible at the moment to have different stroke-width per subpath since it's all in one element.

Feel free to explain further on how you need the connected lines join, an illustration might help.

Have a look at the [tubefy examples](http://owl3d.com/svg/tubefy/) for how to do variable-width stroking and other neat effects with svg and some scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added a picture of the problem I am facing, the lines with different strokes are not connected and the endpoints does not align with the other lines